# Change Gluster Volume Type

Tags: disk-volume, convert

I would like to change a striped-replicate volume to striped-distributed volume, is this possible without rebuilding everything/data loss?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you might be able to change from a replicated to distributed set up by adding more bricks, but my knowledge on this is limited so I'm not posting this as an answer.  See this discussion:  http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.file-systems.gluster.user/5185

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be possible, but the path is not a cheap one.

1. Create a new set of nodes, equal to the one you already have, and large enough to accept all of the data.
2. Add the new volumes in. As this raises the node-count to 2x, Gluster is smart enough to notice you want a 'distributed-replicated-striped' setup.
3. Trigger self-heal to get things distributed around.
4. Fail half of your nodes, and reduce the 'replica' count to 0.

It can't be done directly.